# Unmarshaling a structure containing a variable-size array of a structure

Tags: c#, arrays, structure, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall an array of variable length of a structure nested inside another structure as in the following code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CardInfoRequest 
{
    public ulong CardId;
    public byte AppListLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public CardApp[] AppList;
}
[Serializable()]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CardApp
{
    public ulong CardAppId;
    public byte SomeInformation;
}
```

And I am unmarshalling it by doing:

```
        var lDataPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pSize);            
        Marshal.Copy(pData, 0, lDataPointer, pSize);
        var lResult = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lDataPointer, typeof(CardInfoRequest));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lDataPointer);
```

Where pData is a byte array containing the marshalled structure and pSize is its size in runtime (18 when the array has one item, 27 when the array has two items and so forth...).

However, no matter the size in bytes of the stream, whenever I unmarshall it I am always getting AppList.Length == 1.

Can I unmarshall it correctly? Should I do it byte by byte?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pinvoke marshaller has no idea what size array it needs to create.  A fixed-size buffer cannot work either.  You have to do it in two steps, first unmarshal the first 2 members, you now know the array size from AppListLength.  Create the array, then unmarshal the array elements one by one in a loop.

So roughly (untested)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct CardInfoRequestHeader 
{
    public ulong CardId;
    public byte AppListLength;
}

public struct CardInfoRequest 
{
    public CardInfoRequestHeader Header;
    public CardApp[] AppList;
}

...

var req = new CardInfoRequest();
req.Header = (CardInfoRequestHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pData, typeof(CardInfoRequestHeader));
req.AppList = new CardApp(req.Header.AppListLength);
pData += Marshal.SizeOf(CardInfoRequestHeader);
for (int ix = 0; ix < req.AppList.Length; ++ix) {
    req.AppList = (CardInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pData, typeof(CardInfo));
    pData += Marshal.SizeOf(CardInfo);
}
```

Beware the `ulong` and `Pack = 1` are Red Flags, unmanaged data rarely looks like that.  The code snippet does make the hard assumption that Pack=1 is accurate.